# Autcomplete con array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

¡Hola!
Necesito usar la función autocomplete en "N" cantidad de inputs. Es decir, en cada input de una fila, insertar un nuevo dato y que siga repitiéndose dicha función (autocomplete).

**NOTA*
El código que agregaré, lo tomé de* [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429866/how-to-use-array-in-autocomplete-textbox-jquery).

```js
var availableTags = [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp"];
var availableTagsCode = ["1", "2", "3"]; 
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var index = availableTags.indexOf(ui.item.value);
        $("#tags_code").val(availableTagsCode[index]);  
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tags" name="name">
<input id="tags_code" name="code"><br><br>
<input id="tags" name="name">
<input id="tags_code" name="code"><br><br>
<input id="tags" name="name">
<input id="tags_code" name="code"><br><br>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Hugo. No has dicho nada sobre lo que has intentado hasta ahora y cual es el problema concreto que se presenta. Pásate por el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y revisa el apartado sobre como [realizar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Ese ejemplo que pones ocupa 2 librerias

- jQuery
- JQuery UI

Cabe mencionar que estar repitiendo las `ID` de los elementos HTML, esto no lo puedes hacer, los ID son únicos, SIEMPRE!
Yo reemplacé los Id por class

Para seleccionar varios elementos a la vez, puedes usar el selector de jQuery por clase `$(".NombreDeLaClase")` esta selección funciona para todo.

*Nota: En javascript puro esto no es posible y deberías hacer un `for`*

Luego queremos enlazar un `input` con un segundo `input`, para esto al primero agregamos un atributo llamado `data-target` el cual indicará la `id` del segundo.

Dentro de la función `select` obtenemos el `input` que gatilla el evento mediante `event.target` luego buscamos su propiedad `data-target` que tiene guardad la id del segundo input. Y a este último agregamos el valor correspondiente

```js
var availableTags = [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp"];
var availableTagsCode = ["1", "2", "3"]; 

$( ".tags" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: availableTags,
     select: function (event, ui) {
        var index = availableTags.indexOf(ui.item.value);
        $("#" + $(event.target).attr("data-target")).val(availableTagsCode[index]);  
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="tags" data-target="code1" name="name">
<input name="code" id="code1"><br><br>

<input class="tags"  data-target="code2"  name="name">
<input name="code" id="code2"><br><br>

<input class="tags"  data-target="code3"  name="name">
<input name="code" id="code3"><br><br>
```